# Should I use an Affiliate Selling program at my website?

Tags: affiliate

I'm almost done with my website to publish it.

I realize I may not have enough visitors at the very beginning nor clicks on links which are things I will be working on over time.

I have adsense in place and was looking for more options and suggestions. And since it is a gaming website, I was thinking I could use some sort of Affiliate Programs like Amazon that will display Products related to my site content like CD Games, Strategy guides, etc.

I would like to know from those who used it and are far more experienced then I am:

1. **What programs are worth using and are available to pay you with
   paypal/gcheckout ?**
2. What should I be careful with when using those?
3. Any other advices or ideas of what could I be using/trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm probably only slightly more experienced then you are but here's the info I have:

1. From what I've seen most Affiliate networks allow payment via PayPal, but unless you have a specific reason you can only receive payment this way I'd put the programs they offer at a higher priority then payment options (If they don't have offers that meet your needs you're not going to earn any money any way).
2. I'd make sure to research available programs early on. You don't want to build a whole section or even site dedicated to one game that has no related affiliate offers. To start I'd also recommend promoting programs from well known brands (it's a lot easier to get someone to buy from Amazon.com then it is from gaming-site-no-one-has-ever-heard-of.com)
3. I've not tested this myself but in reading a lot of people recommend mixing affiliate with CPA ads as it's a lot easier to get someone to fill out a form for a free whatever then it is to get someone to buy something.

Hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: thanks for your input, about payment options, i live in brazil and recently google checkout has arrived it here and paypal while it was always available it has improved the banking system allowing both to pay me without problems but i highly doubt about many other system, if they can pay me direct that is awesome but i dont belive most can so having either gcheckout or paypal would be a must.

Comment: 2. that is true but i only know about amazon heheheh that is why i was looking for more advices of other programs alike. really appreciate your input, thanks once again

Comment: There's tons of networks that work with big brands. commission junction, Pepper Jam Network, Share A Sale and Google Affiliate Network are the ones I can think of off the top of my head, but there are quite a few others.

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning you probably won't have enough visitors to make money at all, all ad networks and affiliate systems will only get you a ridiculously low amount of money if at all (I have a site that makes approximately $10/year from affiliate programs).

I've seen recommendations to start the site with no ads and affiliate links and concentrate on building traffic (and people are more likely to recommend your site to their friends if the site looks non-commercial and is not full of ads and affiliate links), later - when you have the traffic level to support ads and affiliate links you add them.

Whatever you are using, test it first on some low value page and see it doesn't hurt your user experience before rolling it out site-wide, and test the result after roll out, if it doesn't work switch to a different network.

Comment: Thanks for you input. This much i know, it is not like i am neglecting it, i have past experience with adsense and made a fansite that once i published it, took about 3 months to produce 10 bucks, but i was interested in knowing more about those system like amazon, since i am doing a gamming site if the site displays things like games for sales and such it my actually make a good profit but never used those kinda of programs before so i am not sure if they are worthed, profitable or which ones would pay me thru paypal or gcheckout

Comment: @Prix - Amazon can pay you in Amazon gift cards, may be worth while if you read lots of books